# C#: For loop not iterating

Tags: c#, for-loop, iteration, loops

I have a for loop that for each item in a listbox it will perform a sub. Whats weird is the for loop didnt iterate at all. I had to force it to iterate to the first item but after if finished performing all the subs for that item it just stopped.

How can I make it keep iterating for each item in the listbox?

Heres my code:

```
listBox7.SelectedIndex = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < listBox7.Items.Count; i++)
{
    sub1();
    sub2();

    listBox1.Items.Add(listBox7.SelectedItem.ToString() + "\r");

    while (listBox7.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
    {
        listBox7.Items.Remove(listBox7.SelectedItems[0]);
    }

    webBrowser1.Navigate("http://www.google.com");
}
```

Comment: are you sure `listBox7.Items.Count` is greater than 0?

Comment: What's your loop supposed to do? It never uses `i`, only `SelectedItem` - those are very different. Are you iterating over `listBox7` using `SelectedIndex`/`SelectedItem`? Don't do that.

Comment: also, rename your listboxes to have meaningful names

Comment: are you change listBox7 Item selection on sub1 or sub2?

Comment: @DarthVader Yes I can input items into the listbox

Comment: @minitech Hmm what do you mean I never used i? In other for loops I didnt use it and it iterated no problem :/. Im iterating it with the selecteditem I think. Basically I want it to iterate, stop on the item, do the subs, then move to the next item, then repeat

Comment: @KeithNicholas +1 Also the `sub1` and `sub2`.

Comment: @user1017524: Well, it iterates no problem, it's just that you don't appear to be doing anything with it.

Comment: @user1017524: You never use `i`. It appears to be for iteration. A little confusing.

Comment: @minitech Hmm very strange error indeed. How would I incorporate i then? Would I need to add i++ inside the for loop?

Comment: @user1017524: No, you'd use `Items[i]` instead of `SelectedIndex`/`SelectedItem`. But you've already got the answer you need, it looks like.

Comment: @minitech Actually, no the answer didnt work. Also I dont see how adding Items[i] will help. The only lines of code that use that is the code to add the selecteditem to another listbox and the one to remove the selected item :/

Comment: @user1017524: You do it repeatedly for apparently no reason. Can you explain your code a bit more?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are most likely removing all of the items in the inner while statement, leaving nothing to iterate on in the second pass.

If your listBox1 contains more than 1 item, an exception will always be thrown on the following line:

```
listBox1.Items.Add(listBox7.SelectedItem.ToString() + "\r");
```

because there is no longer a selected item.

This is why exception handling, even if you are just testing something, is critical.

If your goal is to process every item in listBox7, then you can accomplish this by moving the following line:

```
listBox7.SelectedIndex = 0;
```

inside the for loop, above the line

```
sub1();
```

Comment: That would be the case when all the items are selected in listbox7. If not the loop would still execute ofcourse but will do nothing ...

Comment: @Ajai: Indeed; that's why I qualified the statement with "most likely". But that scenario fits with what the OP reported the problem to be.

Comment: @competent_tech I dont think its that cause not all the items are selected, only 1

Comment: @user1017524: Updated my answer with more comments.

Comment: @competent_tech Strange, I put it inside the for loop, but still, once its done with the first item it just stops. Should I put listBox7.SelectedIndex = 0; above the sub and at the end of the loop?

Comment: @competent_techn Nevermind, I put the selectedindex = 0 code in the end of the for loop and it selects the second item, but doesnt perform the subs for it :/

Comment: @user1017524: First, you should move the SelectedIndex directly above sub1 and delete the one outside the for loop (in case there are no items in listbox7). Second, you should add a try/catch block either inside or outside the loop; I suspect that you are encountering an exception. Third, you should step through the code in debug to see where it is failing. If, for example, the call to webbrowser1 is throwing an exception, that is your problem. If you are making it through the loop a second time, then the issue is most likely with the implementation of sub1/sub2.

Comment: @competent_tech I already added a try catch to it and no errors came up. I already moved the SelectedIndex inside the for loop. I am going to debug I guess and see what happens